# Hive lag function issues

Tags: apache, hive, hiveql

I have a orders table created in Hive.

```
create table orders
( order_date TIMESTAMP,
product_id INT,
qty INT
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I wish to execute a query similar to the following :

```
select product_id, order_date,
lag (order_date,1) over (ORDER BY order_date) AS prev_order_date
from orders
where product_id = 2000;
```

I’m referring to [Windowing in Hive](https://github.com/hbutani/SQLWindowing/wiki)

I’m not sure I have got the syntax – do we have to switch between the modes even within the single query?

```
hduser@cldx-1151-1044:~/hadoop_ecosystem/apache_hive/hive_installation/hive-0.9.0/bin$ hive --service windowingCli
WARNING: org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.EventCounter is deprecated. Please use org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter in all the log4j.properties files.
Hive history file=/tmp/hduser/hive_job_log_hduser_201306211707_783850714.txt
hive> wmode;
windowing mode is off
hive> select * from orders;
OK
2007-09-25 00:00:00     1000    20
2007-09-26 00:00:00     2000    15
2007-09-27 00:00:00     1000    8
2007-09-28 00:00:00     2000    12
2007-09-29 00:00:00     2000    2
2007-09-30 00:00:00     1000    4
Time taken: 37.862 seconds
hive> select product_id, order_date;wmode windowing;lag ('order_date,1') over (ORDER BY order_date) AS prev_order_date; wmode hive; from orders;
BR.recoverFromMismatchedToken
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.Exception do not match. Expected 4 but got 5
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1400)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingException.<init>(WindowingException.groovy:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell.parse(WindowingShell.groovy:72)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell.execute(WindowingShell.groovy:126)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.cli.WindowingClient3.executeQuery(WindowingClient3.groovy:28)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.cli.WindowingClient3$executeQuery.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingHiveCliDriver.processCmd(WindowingHiveCliDriver.groovy:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver$processLine.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingHiveCliDriver.main(WindowingHiveCliDriver.groovy:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

hive> wmode windowing;
hive> select product_id, order_date,lag ('order_date',1) AS prev_order_date from orders;
BR.recoverFromMismatchedToken
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.Exception do not match. Expected 4 but got 5
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1400)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingException.<init>(WindowingException.groovy:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:54)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell.parse(WindowingShell.groovy:72)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell.execute(WindowingShell.groovy:126)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.runtime.WindowingShell$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.cli.WindowingClient3.executeQuery(WindowingClient3.groovy:28)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.cli.WindowingClient3$executeQuery.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingHiveCliDriver.processCmd(WindowingHiveCliDriver.groovy:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver$processLine.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.sap.hadoop.windowing.WindowingHiveCliDriver.main(WindowingHiveCliDriver.groovy:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

While the syntax error may be the reason, is there another cause?

Answer (score 0):

The exception trace is from a Groovy bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6080 . Exception classes implemented in Groovy and compiled on Java 6 will fail at runtime with Java 7 in most cases.

A workaround is to implement exception classes in Java, compile the groovy source with Java 7 or switch to Java 6 for runtime.